# Regex to identify and extract structured information

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I am parsing an unstructured text file that contains structured bits of information. It is straightforward to write a regular expression to identify and extract the structured strings. It seems like there should also be a straightforward way to use the regular expression to extract the *individual components* of information from the string.

Here's a simplified example of what I'm doing:

Structure of information:

```
Integer1 - Phrase1 (Phrase2) (Integer2)
```

I am able to build up a regular expression to identify that structure. This seems to work (even if it is not an optimal regex pattern):

```
import re

white='\s' # whitespace
integer='\d+'
paren_integer = '\(' + integer + '\)' # integer contained within parentheses
phrase = '.+' # one or more words
paren_phrase = '\(.+\)' # one or more words contained within parentheses
dash = '-'

exp = re.compile(integer + white + dash + white+ phrase + white + paren_phrase + white + paren_integer)
structured_string = exp.match(string_to_search)

print(structured_string)
# 'Integer1 - Phrase1 (Phrase2) (Integer2)'
```

Once I have identified the structured strings I can certainly write some piece of code to parse and extract the information from the structured strings, but it seems like there should be a simpler way using the components of the regular expression, maybe by passing the regex components in a list instead of the concatenated regex string. Something like the following:

```
regex_components = [integer, white, dash, white, phrase, white, paren_phrase, white, paren_integer]
exp = re.compile(regex_components)
data_components = exp.match(string_to_search)

print(data_components)
# [Integer1, ' ', '-', ' ', Phrase1, ' ', (Phrase2), ' ', (Integer2)]
```

Is this possible? Is there a smarter way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: @AdrianHHH thanks for the suggestion but it wouldn't have helped. My knowledge of regular expressions was too basic to realize "capturing" with groups was what I was looking for. The tutorials I read through either glossed over groups or the explanation was too buried. Again, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily match with groups (`()`) like so:

```
import re
compiled_re = re.compile(r"(\d+) - ([^(]+) \(([^)]+)\) (\d+)")
result = compiled_re.findall("1234 - Lesson 1 (date 1/1/2018) 5678")
print(result)  # [('1234', 'Lesson 1', 'date 1/1/2018', '5678')]
```

I have also increased the efficiency of your regex, to prevent exponential backtracking.